# Not getting correct object from vector

Tags: c++

i am having problem getting the correct object out from the lines

> Cell cF = fList[rand() % fList.size()];//choose random frontier cell
>
> Cell cl = inList[rand() % inList.size()];//choose random in cell

whenever i debug using visual studio, i can see a Cell will have it's members added due to the method pushToPrimsFrontierList(Cell& c), however when i try to get the object from the inList or fList, it seems like im not getting that same object reference, because its neighbour list is 0 again.what is happening here?

You can see from the image that during the first iteration a startCell is added to the inList, so when im accessing it it will return me only that one object, however that is not the case, it seems like my object is not even push_backed to the inList vector.
[image]

```
#ifndef __CELL_H_
#define __CELL_H_
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Cell{
private:
    int x, y, val;    // cell co-ordinate
    bool visited;
    void setX(int);
    void setY(int);
    vector<Cell> neighbourList;
public: 
    Cell();
    Cell(int,int);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    int getVal();
    vector<Cell>& getNeighbourList();
    void pushToNeighbourList(Cell&);
    void setVal(int);
    void setVisited(bool);
    bool IsVisited();
    bool equals(Cell&);
};

#endif

#ifndef GENMAZE_H
#define GENMAZE_H
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "cell.h"
using namespace std;

class GenMaze{
private:
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int gridSize;
    vector<vector<Cell>> mazeGrid;
    vector<Cell> inList;
    vector<Cell> fList;
public:
    GenMaze(int,int);
    void setRows(int);
    void setCols(int);
    void setGridSize(int);
    int getGridSize();
    int getRows();
    int getCols();
    vector<vector<Cell>>& getMazeGrid();
    void setMazeGrid(vector<vector<Cell>>);
    void setValAt(int,int, Cell);
    void printMazeCoords();
    void printMazeValue();
    bool isOddBlock(int,int);
    void Prims();
    void pushToPrimsFrontierList(Cell&);
    void printCell(Cell&);
    void makePath(Cell&, Cell&);
    void removeFromfList(Cell&);
};
#endif


void GenMaze::Prims(){
    
    Cell startCell = mazeGrid[1][1];//startCell
    inList.push_back(startCell);
    pushToPrimsFrontierList(startCell);
    int randomFrontier= 0;
    int randomIn = 0;

    while (!fList.empty()){
        cout<< "e";
        Cell cF = fList[rand() % fList.size()];//choose random frontier cell
        Cell cl = inList[rand() % inList.size()];//choose random in cell
        for (vector<Cell>::size_type i = 0; i != cl.getNeighbourList().size(); i++) {
            if (cl.getNeighbourList()[i].equals(cF)){
                inList.push_back(cF);
                pushToPrimsFrontierList(cF);
                makePath(cl, cF);
                removeFromfList(cF);
            }
        }
    }
}
void GenMaze::removeFromfList(Cell& c){
    for (vector<Cell>::size_type i = 0; i != fList.size(); i++) {
        if (fList[i].equals(c)){
            fList.erase(fList.begin() + i);
        }
    }
    
}
void GenMaze::makePath(Cell& from, Cell& to){
    cout << "making path";
    //on top
    if ((from.getX() - 2 == to.getX()) & (from.getY() == to.getY())){
        mazeGrid[from.getX() - 1][from.getY()].setVal(0);
    }

    //on right
    if ((from.getX()  == to.getX()) & (from.getY() + 2 == to.getY())){
        mazeGrid[to.getX()][from.getY() - 1].setVal(0);
    }

    //on bottom
    if ((from.getX() + 2 == to.getX()) & (from.getY() == to.getY())){
        mazeGrid[from.getX() + 1][from.getY()].setVal(0);
    }

    //on left
    if ((from.getX()  == to.getX()) & (from.getY() - 2 == to.getY())){
        mazeGrid[from.getX()][from.getY() - 1].setVal(0);
    }


}
void GenMaze::printCell(Cell& c){
    cout << "(" << c.getX() << "," << c.getY() << ")";
}
void GenMaze::pushToPrimsFrontierList(Cell& c){
    //push all Cells around the given Cell c, into the frontier list.
    
    if (!(c.getX() - 2 < 0)){
        Cell topCell = mazeGrid[c.getX() - 2][c.getY()];
            fList.push_back(topCell);
            c.pushToNeighbourList(topCell);
        }
        
        if (!(c.getY() - 2 < 0)){
            Cell leftCell = mazeGrid[c.getX()][c.getY() - 2];
            fList.push_back(leftCell);
            c.pushToNeighbourList(leftCell);
        }
        
        if (!(c.getY() + 2 > getCols() - 1)){
            Cell rightCell = mazeGrid[c.getX()][c.getY() + 2];
            fList.push_back(rightCell);
            c.pushToNeighbourList(rightCell);
        }

        if (!(c.getX() + 2 > getRows() - 1)){
            Cell bottomCell = mazeGrid[c.getX() + 2][c.getY()];
            fList.push_back(bottomCell);
            c.pushToNeighbourList(bottomCell);
        }       
}
```

Comment: just a general remark: don't use `rand()`. search the web for "why not to use rand", to learn why. In short, it doesn't guarantee much.

Answer (score 0):

To the `std::vector` as pretty much to every `STL` collection you cannot put the reference to the object. If you do:

```
Cell c;
std::vector<Cell> myvector1;
std::vector<Cell> myvector2;

myvector1.push_back(c);
myvector2.push_back(c);
```

When you try to modify `c` in `myvector1` the value won't be propagated to `myvector2`. This is because `push_back` adds the element by value not by reference. If you need the real reference to some object you should create collection of pointers to elements and the code should rather look like this:

```
Cell *c = new Cell; 
std::vector<Cell*> myvector1;
std::vector<Cell*> myvector2;

myvector1.push_back(c);
myvector2.push_back(c);
```

Now when you want to modify element beneith `c` you just do:

```
myvector1[indexofc]->somecellfield = othervalue
```